# JMeter - WebDriver Sampler - Unable to handle shadow root

Tags: java, performance, selenium-webdriver, groovy, jmeter-5.0

[image]

I have tried many methods but its not working .I have tried java & Groovey language. No luck please help me on this .

***code*** :-

```
JavascriptExecutor jse =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element =(WebElement)jse.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#ce1 > cui-wizard-internal-ce').shadowRoot.querySelector('#searchInput')");
String js= "arguments[0].setAttribute('value','Test')";
jse.executeScript(js, element);
```

***Error***:-

```
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; import openqa.selen . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : at Line: 23 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; import openqa.selen . . . '' : ( JavascriptExecutor ) driver 

Target exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast void value to org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor
 in inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; import openqa.selen . . . '' at line number 23
at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:87)
at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46)
```